# How to select from database with "where" parameter SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I would like to get one single entry from database. I have such entry model:

```
@Table("USERS")
data class User(@Id val id: String?, val login: String, val password: String)
```

and such controller:

```
@RestController
class MessageResource(val service: MessageService) {
    @GetMapping
    fun index(): List<User> = service.findMessages()

    @PostMapping
    fun post(@RequestBody user: User) {
        service.post(user)
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    fun getByLogin(@RequestParam("login") login: String): User? = service.getByUser(login)
}
```

such service:

```
@Service
class MessageService(val db: MessageRepository) {

    fun findMessages(): List<User> = db.findMessages()

    fun post(user: User) {
        db.save(user)
    }

    fun getByUser(login: String) = db.getByUser(login)
}
```

and repository:

```
interface MessageRepository : CrudRepository<User, String> {
    @Query("select * from users")
    fun findMessages(): List<User>

    @Query(value = "select * from users")
    fun getByUser(login: String): User? {
        val sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = $login"

        return JdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, User::class.java)
    }
}
```

I'm little bit new in SprinBoot and I'm trying to get one entry from database. I tried to run it in repository `getByUser` method, by received error:

```
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 4
```

maybe I did it in wrong way and I have to use another method for filtering all table by row value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `JdbcTemplate().queryForObject` in repository expected to return only 1 row by the SELECT statement.

If your statement is returning multiple results, you should consider to use `JdbcTemplate().query` and the `getByUser()` method in repository should return `List<User>`.
[query doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-)

```kotlin
fun getByUser(login: String): List<User>? {
    val sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = $login"
    return JdbcTemplate().query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(User::class.java))
}
```

**If you expected only one record returned by database. Here is another easier solution.**

If you are using mysql:

```kotlin
fun getByUser(login: String): User? {
    val sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = $login limit 1"
    return JdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, User::class.java)
}
```

If you are using Oracle:

```kotlin
fun getByUser(login: String): User? {
    val sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = $login and rownum=1"
    return JdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, User::class.java)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but `query` method needs mapper or smth like that, because your code doesn't work

Comment: Dear @Andrew, query method needs a mapper, but you can use the mapper which is already provided (etc. BeanPropertyRowMapper), and I updated the doc and the code.

Comment: I got it thank you, but error says that `Error creating bean with name 'messageRepository' defined in com.example.demo.MessageRepository defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on JdbcRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJdbcRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.MessageRepository.getByUser(java.lang.String)! Reason: No property user found for type User!` what does it mean? I need some additional adjustments?

Comment: Is your user table column sync with the properties in class ```User```?
Seems like you have a ```user``` column in your table, but you didn't defined it as a property in your class ```User```.

Comment: yes sure, it syncs and worked well before I started working with fetching user by id :(

Comment: Hi @Andrew, if you expected only one record returned by database. You can refer to another easier solution which just updated in the answer.

Comment: hi again) I don't understand how to fix error which is posted above, I tried your methods from the updated answer, but still have such error :(

Comment: can you try to rename the repository method ```getByUser``` to ```getByLogin```?